# 'String' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

Tags: swift, vapor

When I'm trying to log using `NSLog`, I'm facing this error:

> ```
> remote: /tmp/build_f459d376d1bc10ac2e93e52575ac5ea9/Sources/App/main.swift:368:49: error: argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'
> remote:                     NSLog("FILE NOT AVAILABLE", "TESTNOTI")
> remote:                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
> remote:                                                            as! CVarArg
> ```

**Here is my code:**

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (drop.config["servers", "default", "KeyURL"]?.string ?? "default")) {
    NSLog("FILE AVAILABLE", "TESTNOTI")
} else {
    NSLog("FILE NOT AVAILABLE", "TESTNOTI")
}
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: share some line of code.

Comment: Where does `as! CVarArg` in the error message come from? It's not in the code. Apart from that it's nonsensical to use two arguments in `NSLog` without any placeholder (`%@`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`NSLog` takes as the first argument a *format string,* which is followed
by a list of arguments, which are substituted for the placeholders 
in the format string (compare [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)).

On Apple platforms, you can print a `String` using the `%@` format:

```
let fileName = "the file"
NSLog("File not found: %@", fileName)
```

However, this does not work on Linux platforms (such as Vapor).
Here you have to convert the Swift string to a C string in order to pass
it as an argument to NSLog (and use the `%s` format for C strings):

```
let fileName = "the file"
fileName.withCString {
    NSLog("File not found: %s", $0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using the Vapor framework, and i quote:

> Not all of the core libs (Foundation) is available on Linux yet.

The issue you created over at Vapor has gotten an answer already:
https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/870